# download a file from a link using DrupalWebTestCase?

Tags: files, testing

I'm building a module that has a file download as part of its functionality. The data in it is dynamically populated from the use of forms.

Is there a method in DrupalWebTestCase that will allow me to download it? Or do I resort to wget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `DrupalWebTestCase` has the method [DrupalWebTestCase::curlExec()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--simpletest--drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalWebTestCase%3a%3acurlExec/7), which accepts an array containing the same values used by [curl_setopt()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).